# Не получается передать данные по input

Tags: php, joomla

Меняю компонент в joomla. В файле quiz.html.php вывел форму с полем

```
<input type="text" name="usertest" />
```

В файле question.html.php получаю значение переменной

```
$usertest = $_POST['usertest'];
```

Вывожу через echo, но ничего не отображается, как будто вообще не передается. В Joomla только учусь. Может здесь механизм передачи полей другой. Исправьте меня пожалуйста.

Код формы:

```
<form action="<?php echo JURI::root(true); ?>/index.php<?php if ($Itemid): ?>?Itemid=<?php echo $Itemid; ?><?php endif; ?>" method="post">
    <h1 align="center"><?php AriQuizWebHelper::displayDbValue($quiz->QuizName); ?></h1><br />
    <?php AriQuizWebHelper::displayDbValue($quiz->Description, false); ?>
    <br /><br />
<?php
    if ($canTakeQuiz)
    {
?>
    <input class="start-btn" type="submit" class="button" value="<?php AriQuizWebHelper::displayResValue('Label.Continue'); ?>" />
<?php
    }
?>
    <input type="text" name="usertest" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tmpl" value="<?php echo JRequest::getString('tmpl', ''); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="get_ticket" />
    <input type="hidden" name="quizId" value="<?php echo $quiz->QuizId; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="<?php echo $option; ?>" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Получаю в файле question.html.php

```
<?php
    defined('ARI_FRAMEWORK_LOADED') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');

    $arisI18N = $processPage->getVar('arisI18N');
    $option = $processPage->getVar('option');
    $ticketId = $processPage->getVar('ticketId');
    $questionVersion = $processPage->getVar('questionVersion');
    $questionVersionId = $processPage->getVar('questionVersionId');
    $questionTime = $processPage->getVar('questionTime');
    $quizInfo = $processPage->getVar('quizInfo');
    $statistics = $processPage->getVar('statistics');
    $questionData = $processPage->getVar('questionData');
    $progressPercent = $processPage->getVar('progressPercent');
    $completedCount = $processPage->getVar('completedCount');
    $totalTime = $processPage->getVar('totalTime');
    $hasSplitter = ($questionTime != null && $totalTime != null);
    $itemId = $processPage->getVar('Itemid');
    $tmpl = JRequest::getString('tmpl', '');
    $usertest = $processPage->getVar('$usertest');

    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
    $doc->addScript(JURI::root(true) . '/administrator/components/' . $option . '/js/yui/yahoo-dom-event.js');
    $doc->addScript(JURI::root(true) . '/administrator/components/' . $option . '/js/validators.js');
    $doc->addScript(JURI::root(true) . '/administrator/components/' . $option . '/js/ari.dom.js');
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo JURI::root(true); ?>/index.php<?php if ($itemId): ?>?Itemid=<?php echo $itemId; ?><?php endif; ?>" name="formQue_<?php echo $questionVersionId; ?>" id="formQue_<?php echo $questionVersionId; ?>" style="margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">

<?php echo $usertest; ?>

<h4><?php AriQuizWebHelper::displayDbValue($quizInfo->QuizName); ?></h4>
```

И ноль реакции

Comment: без кода не понятно

Comment: возможно есть какой-то промежуточный редирект

Comment: @Duoxx Код большой, я уже выкладывал его тут с вопросом. Знаю что все данные передаются таким образом: $questionData = $processPage->getVar('questionData');

Comment: Хотя-бы на код формы позырить

Comment: @Duoxx Прикрепил код

Comment: @Duoxx Код вывода тоже приложил

Comment: Достаточно трудно понять куда ссылает action, Покажи лучше конвертированный в html, php

Comment: @Duoxx  ссылается на <form action="/index.php?Itemid=131" method="post">